# Execute script before shutting down in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, gnome, shutdown

When I shut down my computer I want to show some pending tasks that I have to do before leaving the office.

I have a local application to manage those tasks, so basically I just want to run a command, and shut down after I kill the app that was executed.

**I have already tried with these options:**

```
/etc/gdm/PostSession/Default
```

This works only when I select the LogOut option instead Shutdown.

```
/etc/rc0.d/K01mycustomscript
```

Execute a script after X is killed.

```
$HOME/.bash_logout
```

This looks like it does nothing.

```
./app-to-run && sudo shutdown -h now
```

I don't like this for two reasons: it prompts for the sudo password, and I can't use my laptop shutdown button.

I am using Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: Is it really when you shut down, or do you mean when you log out of the GUI?

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you? If so, will you "accept" one?

Comment: No one worked, I think the way to go is modifying the "Shut Down Computer" windows, but that would involve to recompile Gnome I think. I looked for changing the behavior of SHutDown button, but didn't find the way to run my app.

Answer (score 1):

Check out `/etc/rc0.d/README` - it says

```
The scripts in this directory are executed once when entering
runlevel 0.

The scripts are all symbolic links whose targets are located in
/etc/init.d/ .

Generally it is not necessary to alter the scripts in this directory.
Their purpose is to stop all services and to make the system ready
for shutdown.
```

You will need to create a script in `/etc/init.d` and then symlink them to `/etc/rc0.d/` to get scripts to run at shutdown.

Comment: And what's it say? Can you please expand your answer to include the most important information there? Your post is currently flagged as "low quality". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could make an init script in /etc/init.d/ and then configure on which runlevel you want it with chkconfig. I never did what you want, but I would start on this route.

Answer (score 1):

- `/etc/rc0.d/K01mycustomscript` might need to be `/etc/rc0.d/S01mycustomscript`
- make sure it is executable (`chmod 755 /etc/rc0.d/K01mycustomscript` or `chmod 755 /etc/rc0.d/S01mycustomscript`)
- try some logging: add the line `logger 'mycustomscript START'` to the beginning of your script, and `logger 'mycustomscript END'` to the end, shutdown, then look for your log messages in `/var/log/messages`
- note that the convention is instead to create a start/stop script in `/etc/init.d/`, then create symlinks to that script from the appropriate /etc/rc*.d directories, or to use a tool like `chkconfig` or `update-rc.d` to maintain the symlinks (see "Init" wikipedia page)
- [see this similar question](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/run-this-command-when-the-computer-shutdown-or-reboot-683851/)

Answer (score 0):

- Put your executable script somewhere—`/etc/init.d` is recommended.
- Make a symbolic link from this place from `/etc/rc0.d`, starting with `S` (to start this script when getting to runlevel 0.
- I assume that the machine will wait for this script to terminate before shutting down, though I have never tested this.

Answer (score 0):

the /etc/gdm/PostSession/Default way works:

you have to "fix" the gdm (or mdm in my case) upstart skript:

/etc/init/mdm.conf

line15: stop on runlevel [016]

TO:

stop on starting rc runlevel [016]